# Center Image in ScrollView Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, image, scrollview, center

I have a problem with images in a scrollview. I want to scroll the images and they should be centered. There is a problem because each picture has other values in the width.

I tried it with subclassing the scrollview and, but i don't know how to get the actual image in the layoutSubviews-Method.

**Status-Update:**

Now i try it with scrollViewDidScroll:. **But it don't stop on the next image, when i scroll fast.**

The method 
In arrayWithXValues stands the values where the image begins in scrollview.

```
    - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

    CGSize iOSDeviceScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    float middleOfScreenX = scrollView.contentOffset.x + iOSDeviceScreenSize.width / 2;
    for (int i = 1; i < 19; i++) {
        if (i < 17) {
            if (middleOfScreenX > [[arrayWithXValues objectAtIndex:i] floatValue] && middleOfScreenX < [[arrayWithXValues objectAtIndex:i + 1] floatValue] && actualPage != i) {
                ...
                actualPage = i;
                [self killScroll];
            }

        } else {
            if (valMiddleX > [[arrayWithXValues objectAtIndex:i] floatValue]) {
                ...
                actualPage = i;
                [self killScroll];
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)killScroll {
    self.horizontalScrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    self.horizontalScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
}
```

Thanks for all your help

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you are trying to do. Please explain why do you need to center the images, and how the scroll works, where do the images come from? Consider using scrollViewDidScroll: instead of layoutSubviews.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the scrollViewDidScroll:. It is now better but a little bit buggy. Perhaps you can help me. I will update my question.